# Bluetooth notifications for devices in range (Windows Mobile 6.5)

Tags: windows-mobile, bluetooth

I have searched extensively and cannot find a way of doing this.  Is it not possible?

I wanted to get a notification when a bluetooth device (another WM device in this case) comes within range of my Windows Mobile 6.5 device.

I played with the RequestBluetoothNotifications and it worked fine but there are only the following options for notifications:

BTE_CLASS_CONNECTIONS (1)

BTE_CLASS_PAIRING (2)

BTE_CLASS_DEVICE (4)

BTE_CLASS_STACK (8)

There isn't an option for devices in range.

It looks like my only option would be to have a background thread scanning for devices in range?  This approach is really not ideal because the interval would have to be really short to be effective (every min?) and it would drain the device's battery.

Answer (score 0):

I believe mobile devices do NOT do this because, being mobile, they have limited battery life.

Having a Bluetooth radio polling all the time would drain the battery relatively quickly.